# How do we change the Default Stock or Default Source for Magento 2 MSI?

Tags: magento2, msi

How do we change the Default Stock or Default Source for Magento 2 MSI?

There is no option to do so

And when importing stock or Backorder " out of stock threshold " then it activates Default Source for the product instead of our wanted stock (SOH in the picture)

[image]

Comment: it's driving me crazy the strange undocumented things that happen around MSI. My site keeps adding stock there and removing there when it should not.

Comment: I think it is the case : people just started programming .... and let’s see how it works afterwards. Processes should have been used as a use case from real merchants

Comment: the default stock serves as backwards compatibility for things not yet migrated to MSI - MSI is not 100% done. For example for bundles to work, products must be "in stock" in default stock, because bundles aren't MSI migrated yet. Hence why you cant take it off

Comment: Also, the use cases are corporate with an ERP behind Magento. Not me.

Answer (score 0):

The default stock and the default source are hardcoded. On the edit product page, under the "Sources" section, you can see the assigned sources list that was reset by the import process most likely. This data is stored in `inventory_source_item` database table. Make sure that your import doesn't overwrite sources.

Answer (score 0):

This is because MSI isn't complete yet - there is functionality not yet migrated to it.

The default stock is hard coded because of that - backwards compatibility.

There are many extensions and even parts of Magento that still rely on "inventory 1.0" and so the default is hard coded so they don't break.
My default stock mysteriously acquires amounts at times, positive and negative.

This in between status is painful but hey, it's only for another year or so ;)

For example for bundles to work, products must be "in stock" in default stock (real stock or "in stock" status with "back order" on, because bundles aren't MSI migrated yet. It's really annoying, but hey, bundles are hard. (the good news are, when you ship it ships properly from your stock)

When MSI is at 100% coverage, we will be able to change who default is.

Comment: I guess I was wrong about Default vanishing....